# Jquery Validate não executa o evento quando campos são autocompletados

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu estou tentando validar um formulário sem submete-lo. O que eu fiz até agora funciona bem. O problema é quando o preenchimento automático do navegador completa o login e senha que foram salvos para o IP . Se eu apagar o campo auto completado e der focusOut o evento para validar formulário não é disparado.

**Eu estou usando o seguinte :**
jquery -validation - 1.15.0
google- chrome versão 49.0.2623.87 (64-bit )

**Passos :**
1 - Crie um formulário e enviar este formulário.
2 - Faça navegador salvar essas informações como os valores padrão para aquele site.
3 - Volte ao form e apague algum campo "preenchido automaticamente" e tenta provocar algum evento para que jquey-validate faça a validação.

Ele deve validar o campo sem a necessidade de submeter. No meu caso não está acionando o evento e a validação não está ocorrendo.

**formulário**

```
<form name="form" id="loginform" class="lm-login-form" method="post" action="./?_task=login">
  <div id="userid" class="lm-login-item">
    <div class="lm-login-label">
      <label for="rcmloginuser"><roundcube:label name="mail" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="lm-login-field">
      <input name="_user" id="rcmloginuser">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div id="pwdid" class="lm-login-item">
    <div class="lm-login-label">
      <label for="rcmloginpwd"><roundcube:label name="password" /></label>
    </div>
    <div class="lm-login-field">
      <input name="_pass" id="rcmloginpwd" type="password">
      <a href="#" id="showpass">Exibir</a>
    </div>
  </div>

  <p class="formbuttons">
    <input type="submit" id="submitloginform" class="lm-login-submit" value="Entrar">
  </p>
</form>
```

**script para validação**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $( '#loginform' ).validate({
    rules: {
      _user: {
        required: true,
        email: true
      },
      _pass: {
        required: true
      }
    },
  });
});
```

Comment: Poste seu código, assim fica díficil de ver o problema.

Comment: @Diego editei a pergunta

Comment: Pode colocar a parte em que você chama o autocomplete também, por gentileza?

Comment: @LFZiron o autocomplete seria o padrão do browser. Eu não implemento nenhum. Quando se submete o formulário pela primeira vez o broser pergunta se quer salvar login e senha, seria nesse caso.

Comment: Vou tentar fazer algo que talvez solucione esse problema e posto aqui.

Answer (score 0):

Quando o navegador completa os campos automaticamente, o evento que ativa o validate não é convocado. Você precisa convocá-lo manualmente, tente assim:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
 checkInput = setInterval(function(){
  var autoCompleted = false;
  $("#loginform input").each(function(input){
    input = $("#loginform input").eq(input);
    if($(input).val()){
      $(input).val($(input).val());
      $(input).change();
      autoCompleted = true;
    }
    if(autoCompleted){
      clearInterval(checkInput);
    }
  })
 }, 10);
$("#loginform input").focus(function(){
 $(this).change();
 $(this).val($(this).val());
});
$( '#loginform' ).validate({
  rules: {
   _user: {
     required: true,
     email: true
   },
   _pass: {
     required: true
   }
  },
 });
})
```

Comment: Não funcionou. Continua não disparando o evento quando eu apago o campo autocompletado por exemplo.

Comment: Editei a resposta para disparar o evento quando o input fosse focado, pode testar novamente por gentileza?